# Microsoft's Consistency in PowerShell CmdLet Parameter Naming

Tags: powershell, parameters, naming, convention, consistency

Let's say I wrote a PowerShell script that includes this commmand:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

But instead I wrote:

```
Get-ChildItem -Re
```

To save time. After some time passed and I upgraded my PowerShell version, Microsoft decided to add a parameter to Get-ChildItem called "-Return", that for example returns True or False depending if any items are found or not.

In that virtual scenario, do I have I to edit all my former scripts to ensure that the script will function as expected? I understand Microsoft's attempt to save my typing time, but this is my concern and therefore I will probably always try to write the complete parameter name.

Unless of course you know something I don't. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds more like a rant than a question, but to answer:

> In that virtual scenario, do I have I to edit all my former scripts to ensure that the script will function as expected?

## Yes!

You should ***always*** use the full parameter names in scripts (or any other snippet of reusable code).

Automatic resolution of partial parameter names, aliases and other shortcuts are great for convenience when using PowerShell interactively. It lets us fire up `powershell.exe` and do:

```
ls -re *.ps1|% FullName
```

when we want to find the path to all scripts in the profile. Great for exploration!

But if I were to incorporate that functionality into a script I would do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Home -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

not just for the reasons you mentioned, but also for consistency and readability - if a colleague of mine comes along and maybe isn't familiar with the shortcuts I'm using, he'll still be able to discern the meaning and expected output from the pipeline.

---

*Note: There are currently [three](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/215) [open](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/294) [issues](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/295) on GitHub to add warning rules for this in [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) - I'm sure the project maintainers would love a hand with this :-)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not a rant, but I was reading the popular book "Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month" and the author did not specify this requirement in scripts. He just said you can write the short parameter etc. So I thought it's important to ask to know whether Microsoft has anything to say about this that I haven't heard about. Anyway, what you said makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't find any official references, but every single relevant Microsoft employee and MVP I've discussed this topic with agrees without blinking

Comment: Edit: The author of the book I referred to mentioned to *always write the full parameter* when writing scripts later in the chapter. I just wanted to correct this information to give him a proper credit.

Comment: Why you replace `% FullName` with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`, but not with this `ForEach-Object FullName`?

Comment: @PetSerAl backwards compatibility

Comment: @ArtoKalishian Please consider accepting my answer (by clicking the checkmark on the left) if it solves your problem/answers your question

Comment: Sure, and sorry for the delay because I am new to all of this stack overflow thing. I couldn't even vote for you because I'm not allowed yet :)

Comment: Sorry I am unable to find the button. It seems that I still don't have this option.